# Recording streams audio with ffmpeg for Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, google-cloud-speech

Goodnight

I am trying to record audio with the following features:

codec: flac
sampling rate: 16000hz

I am testing with the following line of code:

`ffmpeg -t 15 -i http://198.15.86.218:9436/stream -codec:a flac -b:a 16k example.flac`

But when reviewing the output file, I get the following:

codec: flac
sampling rate: 44000hz

I could guide the correct use of ffmpeg options.

Answer (score 0):

`-b:a` is to set the bitrate*. For sampling rate, you have to use `-ar`.

Use

```
ffmpeg -t 15 -i http://198.15.86.218:9436/stream -codec:a flac -ar 16k example.flac
```

*for a lossless codec, bitrate setting is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

"Free Lossless Audio Codec" Flac is lossless and hence output bit-rate cannot be controlled precisely. -b:a 16k is actually trying to set output bit-rate of audio to 16k bits per second. 
While in your case you need it to be sampled at 16000 Hz. So the correct option would be to use -ar [audio rate]

```
ffmpeg -t 15 -i http://198.15.86.218:9436/stream -c:a flac -ar 16000 example.flac
```

If you want to control the output bit-rate with FLAC encoder then you can use the option -compression_level 0-15 with 5 being default. You can get mode details on controlling other parameters of FLAC ffmpeg encoder [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Options-7).